# Laravel, passing a token from controller to view

Tags: php, laravel

I'm confused as to why this isn't working properly here. In this controller, I'm hitting an API endpoint which, when successful, gives me back an array of tokens. Here, I'm setting one of those tokens to the accessToken variable and trying to pass that to the view to be used in another call there

Controller.php

```
$initialLogin = $authService->initialLogin($newPhone,$request->temp_password,$request->email,$request->password_confirmation);

//this dump and die successfully dumps the token array, so I know I'm getting my tokens
dd($initialLogin);

//Here I'm setting the variable to one of the specific tokens
$accessToken = $initialLogin->auth_access_token;

//Now I'm redirecting to a view, which I'm successfully shown
return redirect(route('auth.phone'))->with('accessToken',$accessToken);
```

When the process is done, after testing the dump and die which does show my tokens, then it redirects me successfully to my view. The problem here is that when dumping the variable on the view, it shows null

view.php

```
<?php dd($accessToken)?>
```

What's going on with this? I can verify that dumping `$initialLogin` in my controller shows the tokens, and I can verify that `$accessToken` is set to the specific token I need, so why isn't it properly passed?

Comment: Your token is located in `Session::`, it's not directly referenced, it's flashed. You can retrieve it in blade with `{{ session()->get( 'accessToken' ) }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, when using `with` a session variable is created, as such, make the following change:

Change,

```
return redirect(route('auth.phone'))->with('accessToken',$accessToken);
```

To

```
return redirect(route('auth.phone', ['accessToken' => $accessToken]));
```

This way, you are actually passing the variable to the view. **Alternatively**, If you want to continue to use `with` then use the session helper (`session('accessToken')`) to access the token.

Comment: Thank you, I think I feel better changing to pass it to the view like you said, that way I can keep using it in the view as a hidden input

Comment: @TomN. you could still use it as a hidden input if it is in the session too. However, either way will work, it's preference I guess.

Comment: One quick question: I'm using the option you tole me to change it to but in the view I cant set it to a hidden input using ```value="{{$accessToken}}" but it instead shows as a URL parameter

Comment: The logic makes sense, but since  I made that change I no longer see it in the session, only the URL param

Comment: @TomN. Do you want it in the session or as a query string?

Comment: I think session would be at least a bit more secure, at least better than having it as a query string that could potentially be modified

Comment: @TomN. 1. The token should be verified so even if it is tampered with, the user can't do anything. Validate your input. 2. If you want it in the session then use `with` and to access it use `session('accessToken')`.

Comment: I see now. So if I keep it as a query string, I can really just use the controller request to grab it instead of using anything in the blade

Answer (score 1):

When you redirect using the with helper, laravel sets your variable in the user's session, not in the view

Try this

```
@if(session('accessToken'))
    {{ session('accessToken') }}
@endif
```